# Iterating over files and preforming operations on them

Tags: shell-script, wildcards

I am relatively new to unix and linux bash scripting and have a few questions:

First here is my script:

```
for fileref in Ref/*.bed; do
    for filename in Data/*.bed; do
            bedops -e 1 $fileref $filename > "${fileref}${filename}.out"
    done
done
```

I have want to perform the command bedops -e with the two files (which are gathered from looping through each directory) as input and have the output file be the concatenation of the two filenames (preferably without the .bed at the end). Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `basename` to both drop the directory(*) and the extension:

```
for fileref in Ref/*.bed; do
    for filename in Data/*.bed; do
        bedops -e 1 $fileref $filename > "$(basename $fileref .bed)-$(basename $filename .bed).out"
    done
done
```

(*) because `for fileref in Ref/*` will iterate on `Ref/File1`, `Ref/File2` so keeping the directories your output file would look like `Ref/File1-Data/File2.out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) to remove parent directories `Ref` and `Data` including the `/` and to remove suffix `.bed` from the filename.

- `${varname##*/}` remove the largest prefix pattern to remove the parent path
- `${varname%.bed}` remove the smallest suffix pattern to remove the `.bed` file extension

```
for fileref in Ref/*.bed; do
    fref=${fileref##*/}
    fref=${fref%.bed}
    for filename in Data/*.bed; do
        fname=${filename##*/}
        fname=${fname%.bed}
        bedops -e 1 "$fileref" "$filename" > "${fref}${fname}.out"
    done
done
```

The same can be achieved with the `basename` command which prints the filename of a given path and optionally removes a suffix:

```
for fileref in Ref/*.bed; do
    for filename in Data/*.bed; do
        bedops -e 1 "$fileref" "$filename" > "$(basename "$fileref" ".bed")$(basename "$filename" ".bed").out"
    done
done
```